# Complex Filter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called Service Agreements . There is a calculated column that depending on the record status will have a value returned for each row , Old Record or Active Record, not both .

So I have a Filter on a Power BI Page, called Include Agreement History , that has values of Active Record and Non Active with a Select All option . However the want now is to have 2 values for this FILTER , Yes and No.

With the calculated column in the Service Agreements,  each row currently gets a single value like Old Record or Active Record. The yes category change would means rows with old record and Active records . For the No option, the rows would be only the old records .  Is there a way of getting the values for this filter to change to Yes and No ? In Power BI there does not seem to be this grouping available that can be used in Filters this way.

Comment: Can you please add to your question the tables with few sample rows to illustrate your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can only set the slicer to the values of a column. There is, however, no reason you couldn't add a custom column with
IF(OR('Agreement History'='Active Record', 'Record Status'='Active Record'), "Yes", "No") or something similar. Then set up a slicer that uses this column.

Comment: Can you explain that custom column for a Filter as that gives you the YES option that includes the Old and New Records , but not the records needed in the NO option which is the just the NEW records .